# How to generalize the implementation the .thenby of excel in Java 8?

Tags: java, sorting, java-8

I have the following service class:

```java
public class SheetSorter {

    // sorts the sheet
    public static Sheet sortSheet(Sheet sheet) {
        List<String[]> list = sheet.getSheet().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String[]>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String[] arr1, String[] arr2) {
                if (Long.parseLong(arr1[3]) == Long.parseLong(arr2[3])) {
                    return (int) (Long.parseLong(arr1[4]) - Long.parseLong(arr2[4]));
                }
                else {
                    return (int) (Long.parseLong(arr1[3]) - Long.parseLong(arr2[3]));
                }
            }
        });
        sheet.setSheet(list);
        return sheet;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `sortSheet` methods implements `sort` on `column 4` and `thenby` on `column 5`. Is there any way I can convert this to take an `Integer... columnOrder` as parameter so that this will run sort on `columnOrder[0]` and 'thenBies' (or is it 'thenBys'?) on the remaining arguments supplied in that order?

---

EDIT:

@Holger's Suggestion

```java
// sorts the sheet
public static Sheet sortSheet(Sheet sheet) {
    List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>(sheet.getSheet());
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String[]>() {
        
        @Override
        public int compare(String[] arr1, String[] arr2) {
            if (Long.parseLong(arr1[3]) == Long.parseLong(arr2[3])) {
                return Long.compare(Long.parseLong(arr1[4]), Long.parseLong(arr2[4]));
            }
            else {
                return Long.compare(Long.parseLong(arr1[3]), Long.parseLong(arr2[3]));
            }
        }
    });
    sheet.setSheet(list);
    return sheet;
}
```

Comment: Never use minus to implement a comparator. Even for `int` values, it can overflow. Not to speak of the `long` results you simply cast to `int`, truncating the upper bits.

Comment: Instead of `a - b`, use [`Long.compare(a, b)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#compare(long,long)) resp. the `compare` method of the particular class `Integer.compare(…, …)`, `Double.compare(…, …)`, etc. However, when you use, e.g. `Comparator.comparingLong(arr -> Long.parseLong(arr[3]))`, like the answer also uses, you get the correct behavior for free anyway.

Comment: Code has a tendency to persist and evolve, to be used in scenarios not originally foreseen. Also habits are hard to overcome. So it’s better to always use the `compare` methods instead of minus, to avoid any future trouble, right from the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way is to just compose your `Comparator` based on the int array:

```
public static Sheet sortSheet(Sheet sheet, int...indices) {
    
    if(indices.length == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    
    Comparator<String[]> comp = Comparator.comparingLong(s -> Long.parseLong(s[indices[0]]));
    for(int i = 1; i < indices.length; i++) {
        int e = i;
        comp = comp.thenComparing(Comparator.comparingLong(s -> Long.parseLong(s[indices[e]])));
    }
    
    List<String[]> list = sheet.getSheet().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.sort(list, comp);
    sheet.setSheet(list);
    
    return sheet;
}
```

`comp` above is created by composing other `Comparator`s based on indices after `indices[0]`.

Comment: `Collectors.toList()` does not guaranty to produce a mutable list. To create a guaranteed-to-be-mutable list copy, just use `List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>(sheet.getSheet());`. It’s also more efficient. Alternatively, `sheet.setSheet(sheet.getSheet().stream().sorted(comp).collect(Collectors.toList()));`

Comment: Neat little trick assigning `i` to `e`! Didn't know one could satisfy the 'variables in lambdas must be (effectively) final' constraint by doing so.

Comment: @L.Spillner it acknowledges that you know that the captured value will be `i`’s current value and not reflect the subsequent updates. So it’s logical that this works. But I’d rather use `int index = indices[i]; … Comparator.comparingLong(s -> Long.parseLong(s[index])) …`

Comment: Or `Comparator<String[]> comp = null; for(int index: indices) { Comparator<String[]> next = Comparator.comparingLong(s -> Long.parseLong(s[index])); comp = comp == null? next: comp.thenComparing(next); }`

Comment: @Holger what if `indices` is to contain unpredictable ints like `[3, 4, 2, 0]`?

Comment: @Holger My bad... I did misread `int index = indices[i]` as `int index = i`.

Comment: So, I throw Collection.sort entirely out the window? On a related note, I still didn't get why you assigned i to e (man I'm dumb!).

Comment: @justanotherguy Is that question for Holger? If so, you'd still have to call that sort method.

Comment: The answer still uses `Collections.sort(list, comp);` though you can also use `list.sort(comp);` in Java 8.

Comment: @justanotherguy I still have `.sort()` in the code. But you can also sort the list directly (just note Holger's comment about mutability). `e` is used to have a final variable usable in a lambda expression.

Comment: ernest_k, I have written a solution based upon what you have suggested. Is it a good idea if I post it here as "what I have tried" in the question?

Comment: @justanotherguy not very sure about the rules. But your post already contains your current code.

Comment: oh no, the solution I constructed

Comment: Sure, your choice. I think you can even post an answer!

Answer (score 0):

My Solution based on the accepted answer:

```java
public static Sheet sortSheet(Sheet sheet, Integer... indices) {

    List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>(sheet.getSheet());
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String[]>() {
        
        @Override
        public int compare(String[] arr1, String[] arr2) {
            for (int i = 0; i < indices.length;) {
                if (Long.parseLong(arr1[i]) == Long.parseLong(arr2[i])) {
                    i++;
                }
                else {
                    return Long.compare(Long.parseLong(arr1[i]), Long.parseLong(arr2[i]));
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
    });
    sheet.setSheet(list);
    return sheet;
}
```

Comment: You are not using `indices[i]`. But you can avoid such mistakes by simplifying the loop: `for(int index: indices) { int c = Long.compare(Long.parseLong(arr1[index]), Long.parseLong(arr2[index])); if(c != 0) return c; } return 0;`